# How to make the cell of table fix

Tags: material-ui

I create a table like Table which contains

```
CheckBox Name LastName.
```

When I translate from one page to another I find that the headers Name and LastName translate from one page to another due to the length of their strings.
I added a style for TableCell:

```
width: 40%
```

But this doesn't solve the problem. How can I fix the headers columns to not translate from one page to another due the length of strings?

I'm using material-ui `v1.0.0-beta.16`. I didn't found the option `fixedHeader` to fix the headers of the table.

Comment: When you say 'translate', do you mean 'change' or 'move'? Please clarify the question. Also it is needed that you show source code snippets that are essential to your problem (in this case, HTML and probably also CSS).

Comment: I mean move from one side to another

Comment: You need to give much more information, including relevant HTML+CSS. I am voting to close as "Unclear what you are asking" at the moment.